HA Automation check if value is below level
I have an automation that shuts off devices in my house when I use too much power.
Once some devices are shut down (this part is working correctly), I want to start them back up in a certain sequence (this part is working too). The issue I'm having is that I currently have a wait-for-trigger event between stop and start that checks if the consumption is lower than a value for x time.
wait_for_trigger:
  - trigger: numeric_state
    entity_id:
      - sensor.power_consumed
    for:
      hours: 0
      minutes: 5
      seconds: 0
    below: 1
timeout:
  hours: 0
  minutes: 20
  seconds: 0
  milliseconds: 0

I have the feeling that the issue is, when the value of the power_consumed sensor is below 1 before it comes to this wait_for_triger step, there is no trigger, and thus never gets executed.
I've tried to split up the start and stop in 2 separate automations, this works, but then I don't know how to force start it after 20 min.

We’ve got a similar setup working without a problem.
I first shut off the main consumer and then start the “wait for” step to check if the power usage is low enough for long enough (30 min in our case).
Thoug in theory there could be a delay in my power sensor that’s saving me here.
Did you ever try logging the power_consumed value between the shutoff step and the wait step?
And just to check, you’re sure that power_consumed is the current usage, not the daily cumulative?
